# Issue with GremlinPipeline

Tags: graph, gremlin, titan

I am creating lots of Gremlin pipelines using the following command to query titan graph vertex:

GremlinPipeline pipeline = new GremlinPipeline();

Since I am unable to find any method to release or reset my pipeline, I am creating new instance for each and every vertex that needs to be queried. This is creating a memory hot spot. Is there a way to re-use or reset the pipeline without creating new instance?

I tried using methods pipeline.remove() and pipeline.reset() but no luck.

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: Can you provide any more information about why you need to create so many `GremlinPipeline` instances?  Perhaps some more code to demonstrate what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks for the response! In my scenario, one parent vertex has many child vertices. I am iterating over each of the child vertex to find out whether it is matching some criteria. In order to evaluate whether child vertex is matching criteria or not, I am creating new instances of pipeline for each child to find out whether it has an outgoing edges having edge label "L" and edge property either "P1" or "P2" or "P3". So I wanted to know whether we can create one instance of pipeline and reuse the same for all child vertices.

Let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: Here is the sample code....                                   `code`                                                        for (TitanVertex childVertex : childVertices) {
 GremlinPipeline pipeline = new GremlinPipeline();  // This is where I am creating instances 
 pipeline = pipeline.start(childVertex).outE().has(SCORE).or(someCondition);
 Iterator<Edge> edgeIterator = pipeline.iterator();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider starting your pipeline with the `childVertices`.  In Gremlin Groovy that would be:

```
childVertices._().outE().has(SCORE).or(...
```

or I guess if you were using GremlinPipeline directly, then something like:

```
new GremlinPipeline(childVertices).has(SCORE).or(....
```

Comment: I tried the second option "new GremlinPipeline(childVertices).has(SCORE).or(... but got the following exception.                                       "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
 at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.QueryUtil.constraints2QNF(QueryUtil.java:163)

Comment: Where childVertices is of type List<TitanVertex>. Is that causing problem?

Comment: can you just do: `new GremlinPipeline(childVertices)` and let it pass through without any extra filters or anything? in that way it should just output each of the vertices in `childVertices`.  Please see if that works without error.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I will try and let you know.